# Get text above table MS Word

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, office-2007

This one is probably a little stupid, but I really need it. I have document with 5 tables each table has a heading. heading is a regular text with no special styling, nothing. I need to extract data from those tables + plus header. 
Currently, using MS interop I was able to iterate through each cell of each table using something like this:

```
app.Tables[1].Cell(2, 2).Range.Text;
```

But now I'm struggling on trying to figure out how to get the text right above the table. 
Here's a screenshot: [image]

For the first table I need to get "I NEED THIS TEXT" and for secnd table i need to get: "And this one also please"

So, basically I need last paragraph before each table. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 10):

Mellamokb in his answer gave me a hint and a good example of how to search in paragraphs. While implementing his solution I came across function "Previous" that does exactly what we need. Here's how to use it:

```
wd.Tables[1].Cell(1, 1).Range.Previous(WdUnits.wdParagraph, 2).Text;
```

Previous accepts two parameters. First - Unit you want to find from this list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdunits.aspx
and second parameter is how many units you want to count back. In my case 2 worked. It looked like it should be  because it is right before the table, but with one, I got strange special character: `♀` which looks like female indicator.

Comment: I thought googling for "How to get text above a table in word" would be completely futile, but I was desperate and I tried. This led me to a solution. Thanks!
I C# with netoffice, you want to use the previousSibling() method on table.

Answer (score 3):

You might try something along the lines of this.  I compare the paragraphs to the first cell of the table, and when there's a match, grab the previous paragraph as the table header.  Of course this only works if the first cell of the table contains a unique paragraph that would not be found in another place in the document:

```
var tIndex = 1;
var tCount = oDoc.Tables.Count;
var tblData = oDoc.Tables[tIndex].Cell(1, 1).Range.Text;
var pCount = oDoc.Paragraphs.Count;
var prevPara = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= pCount; i++) {
    var para = oDoc.Paragraphs[i];
    var paraData = para.Range.Text;

    if (paraData == tblData) {
        // this paragraph is at the beginning of the table, so grab previous paragraph
        Console.WriteLine("Header: " + prevPara);
        tIndex++;
        if (tIndex <= tCount)
            tblData = oDoc.Tables[tIndex].Cell(1, 1).Range.Text;
        else
            break;
    }
    prevPara = paraData;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Header: I NEED THIS TEXT

Header: AND THIS ONE also please
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Your solution gave me an idea on how to implement this. After spending some time, I figured out an easier way to do it. I'll post this as an answer.